# link axis between different plot (no subplots) using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here is my question. I know there is a simple way to link the axis of different plot if they are subplots in the same figure this way :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
```

But I wonder if there is a way to do the same link (when zooming on figure 1, I get the same zoom on figure 2 on one particular axis) when defining 2 different Figures (I want those graph to appear far from each other so I guess that I can't put them in the same Figure...)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503423/how-to-enable-disable-easily-shared-axis-using-matplotlib follow on question

Comment: on stackoverflow you should accept the answer (and maybe upvote it), if it answers your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply do the same thing, but with a different figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, sharex=ax1)
```

Comment: Well well well... Indeed ! :) That was quite simple ! :D Thanks a lot !

Comment: As an aside, this does not work with `f1, a1 = plt.subplots(); f2, a2 = plt.subplots(sharex=a1)`

Comment: But, as expected, it works with `f1, a1 = plt.subplots(); f2, a2 = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'sharex': a1})`. Why the duplicated keywords?