# How to enable/disable easily shared axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The [previous answer from tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482422/link-axis-between-different-plot-no-subplots-using-matplotlib) on how to create shared axis for plots which are not on the same figure was perfect :) But I'm now wondering how to disable the shared axis and reenable them without having to redraw or destroy anything ? (I have multiple graphs and I want to add a button that the user can click to disable/enable those shared axes) I found a way :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, sharex=ax1)
```

to create the shared axis and then

```
fig2.delaxes(ax2)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
```

but this require to redraw everything and can take some times. I didnt find a simple function to disable the link. Is there a lighter way than what I did ?

Thanks !

Comment: adding link to the current (Feb 2018) WIP attempts to implement this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9923

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no existing easy way to do this, however I think it *can* be done (it will just take a bit of digging into the `matplotlib` internals).  The way that the axes are linked underneath is by simply using the same locator and formatter  objects for both `axis`.  To link/unlink you will have to copy/make new all of those objects, as well as update some ancillary structures (`_shared_x_axes`, `_shared_y_axes`).  Look at the implementation of `matplotlib.axes.Axes.cla()` for some idea of what you need to do.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1312) against the repo that adds this functionality and the associated [feature request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/318).  If you are comfortable a) installing from source b) using master and c) applying this patch I think the developers would appreciate you testing this.

Comment: Thanks tcaswell ! I'll see what i can do. But I'm not really comfortable with your a) b) and c) since I'm still a beginner with python. But I'll already tried to digg a bit into the module to modify the navigation toolbar so I'll guess I'll digg again ! :)

Answer (score 13):

You can do:

```
ax2.get_shared_x_axes().remove(ax1)
```

References:

- [API docs explaining get_shared_x_axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)
- [API docs describing Grouper.remove](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/cbook_api.html?highlight=grouper#matplotlib.cbook.Grouper.remove)
- (Looks like the remove method was [added to the Grouper object in
  2015](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/2dfb60b852375df5a8b1421f06881db4c8ead3a4))

Comment: Also, when creating a subplot using the `sharex` and/or `sharey` options e.g. `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)`, `ax2.get_shared_x_axes()` contains the list of *all* axes. Hence one would need to do `ax12.get_shared_x_axes().remove(axis)` for each axis. Or better `[ax12.get_shared_x_axes().remove(axis) for axis in axes.ravel()]`.
I am sharing this because it took me more than one try: `ax12.get_shared_x_axes()` is actually not a list but a `Grouper` object + `axes` is a multidimensional numpy array. You might consider adding that to your answer @EEE ;)

Comment: This is now deprecated in matplotlib 3.6. What's the current intended approach?

Comment: ax2._shared_axes['x'].remove(ax2) worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Grouper object that defines which plots are sharing their axes. The Grouper object for x axes can be found in `ax1._shared_x_axes` as well as in `ax2._shared_x_axes`, since it's the same object.

To stop sharing the x axis of the both plots, you can do `ax2._shared_x_axes.remove(ax2)`.

In order to joining them again, do `ax2._shared_x_axes.join(ax1,ax2)`.

If you want to understand better, you can check the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.Grouper). `ax1._shared_x_axes` is a Grouper object, in which ax1 and ax2 are the joint elements.

With the `ax2.get_shared_x_axes()` method you just can read it, but not change it. For aplying modifications, you need to access this object directly with `ax2._shared_x_axes`.