# Independent axis for each subplot in pandas boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, boxplot

The below code helps in obtaining subplots with unique colored boxes. But all subplots share a common set of x and y axis. I was looking forward to having independent axis for each sub-plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(140, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

df['models'] = pd.Series(np.repeat(['model1','model2', 'model3', 'model4',     'model5', 'model6', 'model7'], 20))

bp_dict = df.boxplot(
by="models",layout=(2,2),figsize=(6,4),
return_type='both',
patch_artist = True,
)

colors = ['b', 'y', 'm', 'c', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'k', ]
for row_key, (ax,row) in bp_dict.iteritems():
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    for i,box in enumerate(row['boxes']):
        box.set_facecolor(colors[i])

plt.show()
```

Here is an output of the above code:
[image]

I am trying to have separate x and y axis for each subplot...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the figure and subplots before hand and pass this in as an argument to `df.boxplot()`. This also means you can remove the argument `layout=(2,2)`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=False,sharey=False)
```

Then use:

```
bp_dict = df.boxplot(
by="models", ax=axes, figsize=(6,4),
return_type='both',
patch_artist = True,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...limiting the layout to plt.subplots mandates the number of grid boxes to be equal to subplots needed. Can you suggest a relatively easy way to accommodate 13 subplots in 2xn layout? And if I use layout argument in df.boxplot then the axis stay shared..

Answer (score 1):

You may set the ticklabels visible again, e.g. via

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)
```

This does not make the axes independent though, they are still bound to each other, but it seems like you are asking about the visibilty, rather than the shared behaviour here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but I meant to have independent axes with independent ranges for all of them (especially the yaxis where ylims need to be separate for each subplot). Bound ranges are inhibiting the views of boxes having lower data range but higher axis range.

Comment: In that case refer to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really think it is necessary to un-share the axes *after* the creation of the `boxplot` array, you can do this, but you have to do everything 'by hand'. Searching a while through stackoverflow and looking at the `matplotlib` documentation pages I came up with the following solution to un-share the `yaxes` of the `Axes` instances, for the `xaxes`, you would have to go analogously:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoLocator, AutoMinorLocator

##using differently scaled data for the different random series:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.asarray([
        np.random.rand(140),
        2*np.random.rand(140),
        4*np.random.rand(140),
        8*np.random.rand(140),
    ]).T,
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
)

df['models'] = pd.Series(np.repeat([
    'model1','model2', 'model3', 'model4',   'model5', 'model6', 'model7'
], 20))

##creating the boxplot array:
bp_dict = df.boxplot(
    by="models",layout = (2,2),figsize=(6,8),
    return_type='both',
    patch_artist = True,
    rot = 45,
)

colors = ['b', 'y', 'm', 'c', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'k', ]

##adjusting the Axes instances to your needs
for row_key, (ax,row) in bp_dict.items():
    ax.set_xlabel('')

    ##removing shared axes:
    grouper = ax.get_shared_y_axes()
    shared_ys = [a for a in grouper]
    for ax_list in shared_ys:
        for ax2 in ax_list:
            grouper.remove(ax2)

    ##setting limits:
    ax.axis('auto')
    ax.relim()      #<-- maybe not necessary

    ##adjusting tick positions:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())

    ##making tick labels visible:    
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=True)

    for i,box in enumerate(row['boxes']):
        box.set_facecolor(colors[i])

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

**Explanation**:

You first need to tell each `Axes` instance that it shouldn't share its `yaxis` with any other `Axis` instance. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761736/2454357) got me into the direction of how to do this -- `Axes.get_shared_y_axes()` returns a [Grouper object](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/cbook_api.html?highlight=grouper#matplotlib.cbook.Grouper), that holds references to all other `Axes` instances with which the current `Axes` should share its `xaxis`. Looping through those instances and calling `Grouper.remove` does the actual un-sharing.

Once the `yaxis` is un-shared, the `y` limits and the `y` ticks need to be adjusted. The former can be achieved with `ax.axis('auto')` and `ax.relim()` (not sure if the second command is necessary). The ticks can be adjusted by using `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator()` and `ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator()` with the appropriate [Locators](https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html). Finally, the tick labels can be made visible using `plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=True)` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2176591/2454357)).

Considering all this, @DavidG's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50971301/2454357) is in my opinion the better approach.