# matplotlib subplots selective axis sharing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 8 figures (4 rows, 2 columns). I want all figures to share axes, except for one. Is this possible in matplotlib without doing it by hand?

Example:

```
fig = plt.figure();
ax = fig.subplots(4,2,sharex='all',sharey='all')
for j in np.arange(4):
    plt.sca(ax[j,0])
    plt.plot(np.random.random(5),'.')
    plt.sca(ax[j,1])
    plt.plot(np.arange(5),'.')
plt.sca(ax[0,0])
# Code here to unlink this one axis from the shared system
plt.gca().set_yscale('log',basey=10) # I only want this one axis to be log
```

Comment: I think the fastest way would be to delete that subplot with `ax[0,0].remove()` and create a new one at the same position with `ax[0,0] = fig.add_subplot(421)`. Otherwise you have to 'unshare' the `Axes`, which is a bit tedious.

Comment: Just to add, if you really want to unshare the existing axes, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761736/2454357) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51020046/2454357).

Comment: Removing the axis worked perfectly, thank you!